# How to create full-text catalog as default catalog?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, full-text-catalog

This would save me the redundant `ON MyCatalog` phrase when I create full-text indices.

For example,

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON MyTable
(
    MyField1,
    MyField2,
    MyField3
)
KEY INDEX PK_MyKey ON MyCatalog  /* I want MyCatalog to be default, so I don't have to specify*/
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

With `MyCatalog` set as default catalog, I wouldn't have to specify `ON MyCatalog` every time I want to create a full-text index.  So how can I make MyCatalog default on this database?